# Как записать выражение (-1)^(k+1) без pow?

Tags: c++, c

Как записать `(-1)^(k+1)` без использования функции `pow`?

Comment: Резонный вопрос, а зачем?

Comment: Можно циклом, но оно вам надо?

Comment: Да, на лабе сказали оптимизировать код, тоесть без pow, но не знаю как

Comment: Ниже ответ условным оператором - оптимальней по времени, но строк больше :)

Comment: k только целого типа и больше -1?

Comment: @banme Вопрос очень хороший, но думаю тут все в порядке. Если бы тут подразумевались не только натуральные числа и 0, то от `pow()` было бы не отказаться или даже `pow()` вообще не подходил бы.

Comment: @tutankhamun если степень можно представить в виде `n/m` (т.е. в виде обыкновенной дроби) и `m` - нечетное, то без `pow` можно обойтись.

Comment: @alexolut напишите альтернативный ответ. Топикстартер-то не я

Comment: @tutankhamun так я не на вопрос как таковой комментарий писал, а на Ваш комментарий отвечал.

Comment: @alexolut На самом деле без `pow()` получится обойтись всегда, поскольку для целых чисел есть простые и достойные замены, а возведение `-1` в степень, являющуюся нецелым двоичным числом с ограниченной точностью даст комплексное значение, поскольку такое число представить в виде дроби с нечетным знаменателем не получится

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
int result;

if (k%2 == 0)
    result = 1;
else 
    result = -1;
```

Answer (score 10):

Мне понравился ответ @Mira и @tutankhamun

Но если используете это выражение **в цикле** есть еще более оптимальный

```
c = -c;
```

К примеру

```
c = -1;
for(int k=0; k<n;k++){
  // дествие с значение (-1)^(k+1) исползуете пересенное _c_
  c = -c; // меняем значение _c_
}
```

Comment: А за что минус? Ответ по сути верный.

Comment: @VladD спасибо. Да , мне тоже интересно зачем ?

Comment: Не минусовал, но зачем цикл, если знак результата напрямую зависит от модуля степени по двойке?

Comment: @KromStern про цикл сказано в контексте того, что он **уже есть** и нужно получить значение для `(-1)^(k+1)` в процессе прохода по циклу.

Answer (score 9):

Можно так:

```
(k & 0x01) ? 1 : -1
```

или так:

```
((k & 0x01) << 1) - 1
```

Comment: `~(k & 0x01) - 1`  - а такой?

Comment: @Saidolim Не взлетит. При четном k - будет -2; при нечетном -1

Comment: Интересно, за что мне минус влепили?

Comment: @Saidolim Тоже не катит - для нечетных 0 получается

Answer (score 8):

В зависимости от четности степени это будет выглядеть как:

```
if (k%2 == 0) ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Вот еще вариант, для тех кто понимает, без условных операторов:

```
1 - 2 * (k % 2)
```

Comment: Имхо самый лучший, это как раз без ветвления, например в `glsl` это сильно предпочтительнее

Comment: я не знаток с++, а разве так `1 - k % 2 * 2`  нельзя?

Comment: Можно и так конечно, скобки для того чтобы не вспоминать приоритеты. Я однажды ошибся в приоритете тернарного обператора и запятой и жестоко за это поплатился жестким, противоестественным, ночным сексом с отладчиком.

Answer (score 2):

Объединение ответов [@Mira](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475730/176217) и [@tutankhamun](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/475756/176217) в один:

```
k % 2 ? 1 : -1;
```